# how can write the declaration for a sub class which has an interface and cannot be accessed

Tags: java

how can write the declaration for a sub class which has an interface and cannot be accessed by other classes

I tried with this but that is correct ?

```
private class Foo implements Runnable 
{
    public void run()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have such a requirement? How are you going to use this class?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bar {
  Foo f;
  private class Foo implements Runnable() {
     public void run() { }
  }
}
```

You can do it within a public class.